# Is the TestCafe team planning to support Gherkin (BDD) officially? If not what is the best way of integrating TestCafe with Gherkins at the moment?

Tags: testing, bdd, e2e-testing, gherkin, testcafe

My team kinda like TestCafe, but there are some reservations against adopting it. The main one being support for Gherkin integration. The gherkin-testcafe npm package and the sample https://github.com/helen-dikareva/testcafe-cucumber-demo seem not ready for primetime yet.

Is it a more reliable way of supporting BDD at the moment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked to the product team. They're the ones that have the authoritative answer.

Comment: This is not a SO question. It is a question for the TestCafe team, who ever they are. Or Quora.

Comment: I changed the question a bit. I should be more interesting for a broader community now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a conversation with colleagues here at the office, we concluded that the best way to

- keep our BDD process,
- use TestCafe and
- write tests in Typescript without adding dependencies on javascript packages that are not the most realiable

was to just use some conventions while writing the TestCafe tests. For example, let's say you are given the following Gherkin file:

```
Feature: Application
As an administrator
I want to be able to view and manage Applications in my account

Scenario: Verify creating and deleting an application
    Given I am in the login page
    When I login to console with allowed user
    And I go to Applications page
    And I add an application
    Then the application is added in the application page
```

Then the feature.ts file would look something like the following:

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';
import {LoginPageModel} from '../pagemodels/login.pagemodel';
import {ApplicationPageModel} from '../pagemodels/application.pagemodel';

let applicationPageModel: ApplicationPageModel = new ApplicationPageModel();
let loginPageModel: LoginPageModel = new LoginPageModel();

fixture(`Feature: Application
   As a administrator
   I want to be able to view and manage Applications in my account
 `);

let scenarioImplementation = async t => {
  let stepSuccess: boolean;

  stepSuccess = await loginPageModel.goToPage(t);
  await t.expect(stepSuccess).eql(true, 'Given I am in the login page');

  stepSuccess = await loginPageModel.login(t);
  await t.expect(stepSuccess).eql(true, 'When I login to console with 
  allowed user');

  stepSuccess = await applicationPageModel.selectPage(t);
  await t.expect(stepSuccess).eql(true, 'And I go to Applications page');

  stepSuccess = await applicationPageModel.addApplication(t);
  await t.expect(stepSuccess).eql(true, 'And I add an application');

  stepSuccess = await applicationPageModel.verifyAddedApplication(t);
  await t.expect(stepSuccess).eql(true, 'Then the application is added in 
  the application page');

 };

test(`Scenario: Verify creating and deleting an application
   Given I am in the login page
   When I login to console with allowed user
   And I go to Applications page
   And I add an application
   Then the application is added in the application page`, 
                                            scenarioImplementation);
```

Comment: Hi @Albino Cordeiro, can we use scenario outline with an external file in testcafe with BDD?

Answer (score 5):

I'm from the TestCafe Team. Fow now, we don't plan to add this functionality in the near future. But I guess [gherkin-testcafe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gherkin-testcafe) is a nice module to start with. This is an open-source module, so there is a good chance that the community will add the required functionality. If you wish, you may go ahead and do this by yourself.